# What happened to Kochanski between season 8 and 10 of Red Dwarf?

Tags: red-dwarf

What happened to Kochanski between season 8 and 10 of Red Dwarf?

At the end of season 8, Rimmer had gone back to the "real" universe and the other 4 had gone to the mirror universe.  After that, what happened?  How were they all reunited and specifically, where did Kochanski go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of the Back to Earth special, we see Lister reading to a memorial to Kochanski, with the implication being that she is dead.

Later in the special, the kids Lister talks to on the bus talk about the events of "Series 9", which was never actually written, shot, or aired. They tell him that Kryten lied about Kochanski being sucked out of an airlock. The truth, according to the kids, is that she was tired of watching Lister wasting his life drinking and went off on her own in Blue Midget. Kryten told Lister she had died in order to spare his feelings (or perhaps because he was jealous of Lister's feelings for Kochanski).

At the end of the Back To Earth specials, Lister resists the hallucinated Kochanski, saying that he knows that the real her is out there somewhere and that he intends to find her.

Answer (score 1):

It is implied she is still alive, or at least Lister assumes so.

In the episode "Entangled" from Series X Lister speculates that

> the woman in stasis, whom later turns out to be Professor Irene Eddington,

is actually Kochanski.